# Multiplying first 2 values of a list and the last two by a different number

Tags: python

```
list1= [1.1, 1.02, 0.4, 1.35, 0.9]

def update(lst):
    nl=[]
    for i in lst:
        nl.append(i*2)
    return nl
```

Currently the function mutiplies all values in the list by 2, but how would i go about only multiplying the first 3 values by 2, and the rest by another number(etc multiplied by 5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list slicing to pick out the first three and last three values. `[:3]` picks the list values to the start to the one before the fourth (index 3). `[3:] picks the fourth to the end.

```
list1= [1.1, 1.02, 0.4, 1.35, 0.9]

def update(lst):
    nl=[]
    for i in lst[:3]:
        nl.append(i*2)
    for i in lst[3:]:
        nl.append(i*5)
    return nl
```